# Son of the Revenge of the Riley Riddles in Reverse Strikes Again

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

Because why not, here's yet another bunch of [these inverted riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22riley+riddles+in+reverse%22), where the solutions are what you'd usually use as the wordplay clues in a Riley Riddle. Here's how it goes:

> **You get three words.**
>   You must find **one solution word** that you can attach..
>
> - to the **beginning** of one of the three words, (you have to figure out which one)
> - somewhere in the **middle** of another, and
> - to the **end** of the remaining word,
>
> so that in each case, a new, single word is formed.

All the words here are very random, and some of the words aren't even all that common, but every clue, result, and solution word is going to be strictly [valid in Scrabble](https://scrabblewordfinder.org/check).

1. **ice - unified - read**
2. **self - my - overt**
3. **over - clad - clay**
4. **ness - scaly - see**

If you get stuck, you can combine the solutions to find the catchphrase of a famous TV detective.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. > **Just**ice un**just**ified read**just**
2. > **one**self m**one**y overt**one**
3. > **more**over cla**more**d clay**more**
4. > **thing**ness sca**thing**ly see**thing**

The phrase is

> Just one more thing, by Colombo